# Angular/JS unexpected early end of program

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try to make my first steps in the world of web developpement with angular (and in javascript in general), and I tried to rewrite some obvious and classical examples in angular. I tried to display a simple message using data biding. So, I wrote this :

```
var app = angular.module("myModule", []);

var myCtrl = function($scope) {
$scope.message = "YES";
};  // "unexpected eraly end or program" here
    // "expected an identifier and instead saw '(end)'. Missing semicolon"
app.controller("myCtrl", myCtrl);
```

I tried this in plunker and it works but it shows me two warnings :

- "unexpected early end of program" (in line 5)
- "expected an identifier and instead saw '(end)'. Missing semicolon" (in line 6)

I'm really not very comfortable with javascript syntax and I didn't find a clear explanation about this until now. Can you help me please to understand this point?
Thanks

Comment: Where's the plunkr? Are you 100% sure this is the only code you added?

Comment: here is my plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/AsN0g1A1mJ8a5ASgr0Ep?p=preview

Comment: That's not the same code you posted and it doesn't show the error you mentioned when I open the console with Chrome. You need to be more careful if you want others to help.

Comment: Sorry for my errors, I was using the same plunker until now. It's why you didn't see the version that I posted in my initial post. Can you see it now please?? It's in the same link : https://plnkr.co/edit/AsN0g1A1mJ8a5ASgr0Ep?p=preview A list thing : I was no talking about an error but a warning that the plunker editor shows to me..

Comment: Where is the warning? I am not sure where it would be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing semicolon after:

```
$scope.message = "YES"
```

Comment: The plunkr doesn't have the error if I remove the semi-colon. How does this prove anything? @salamanka44 You should post your plunkr that has the problem

Comment: @Juan Mendes : it's this one : https://plnkr.co/edit/AsN0g1A1mJ8a5ASgr0Ep?p=preview